# Reading point data from a text file and returning a dictionary

Tags: python

I need to read a text file and return a dictionary where the key is the city name and the coordinates are lists.

Here is what the file looks like:

```
Seattle 3 26
Las_Vegas 11 10
Los_Angeles 4 8
San_Diego 7 5
```

And here is what the code I have tried so far looks like:

```
cities = "cities.txt"
def readPoints(infile):
    cityDictionary = {}
    with open(cities) as fh:
        for line in fh:
            command, description = line.strip().split(' ', 1)
            cityDictionary[command] = description.strip()
    print(cityDictionary)

readPoints(cities)
```

The output with this appears like so:

```
{'Los_Angeles': '4 8', 'Seattle': '3 26', 'San_Diego': '7 5', 'Las_Vegas': '11 10'}
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
{'Los_Angeles': [4.0, 8.0], 'Seattle': [3.0, 26.0], 'San_Diego': [7.0, 5.0], 'Las_Vegas': [11.0, 10.0]}
```

I've also tried changing `command, description = line.strip().split(' ', 1)` to `command, description = line.strip().split(' ')` and I get the error message: `ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Comment: Why did you set `maxsplit` to `1` in `split`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpack them all at the start. For python 3:

```
cities = "cities.txt"
def readPoints(infile):
    cityDictionary = {}
    with open(cities) as fh:
        for line in fh:
            command, *coords = line.strip().split()
            cityDictionary[command] = [float(coord) for coord in coords]
    print(cityDictionary)

readPoints(cities)
```

For python 2:

```
cities = "cities.txt"
def readPoints(infile):
    cityDictionary = {}
    with open(cities) as fh:
        for line in fh:
            data = line.strip().split()
            cityDictionary[data[0]] = [float(coord) for coord in data[1:]] 
    print(cityDictionary)

readPoints(cities)
```

`*coords` puts all remaining arguments into a list called `coords`

Note: this also works if you have an arbitrary number of coordinates.

Comment: I'm just very new to python and based that code off of another forum question, so I didn't fully understand what everything meant.  Thank you for the help, but when I try to run the code with these suggested changes I get the error message: `command, coords = line.strip().split()

ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Comment: it should be `command, *coords = line.strip().split()` don't forget the * in front of `coords`

Comment: when I put in the *, it says invalid syntax.  I'm using python 2.7, if that makes a difference

Comment: Ah ok, I added in for Python2

Answer (score 0):

You could read line by line and either use `line.split()` and assign the split strings to variables like I do below. I chose to use regular expressions. If there's an error parsing a line (if it's an empty line for instance), the loop continues to the next line of input text. Note: I'm only using `StringIO` for demo purposes - see the code below the first example for a more real-world implementation.

```
>>> indata = """
... Seattle 3 26
... Las_Vegas 11 10
... Los_Angeles 4 8
... San_Diego 7 5
... """
>>>
>>> data_dict = {}
>>>
>>> for line in StringIO(indata):
...     try:
...         loc, long, lat  = re.findall(r"\s*(\w+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)", line)[0]
...         print(f"Location: {loc}\nLongitude: {long}\nLatitude: {lat}\n")
...         data_dict[loc] = (long, lat)
...     except (ValueError, IndexError):
...         pass
...         
Location: Seattle
Longitude: 3
Latitude: 26

Location: Las_Vegas
Longitude: 11
Latitude: 10

Location: Los_Angeles
Longitude: 4
Latitude: 8

Location: San_Diego
Longitude: 7
Latitude: 5

>>> data_dict
{'Seattle': ('3', '26'), 'Las_Vegas': ('11', '10'), 'Los_Angeles': ('4', '8'), 
'San_Diego': ('7', '5')}
```

The way the code would look reading in the file:

```
>>> with open('cities.txt', 'r') as f:
...     for line in f:
...         try:
...             loc, long, lat  = re.findall(r"\s*(\w+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)", line)[0]
...             print(f"Location: {loc}\nLongitude: {long}\nLatitude: {lat}\n")
...             data_dict[loc] = (long, lat)
...         except (ValueError, IndexError):
...             pass
```

You could print a message when an exception occurs, or have it written to a debug log if you choose.

**Developer Soapbox**

By the way, I feel it's good practice to read in input text data line-by-line and processes it one at a time. So many programmers these days would default to the easy path of writing code that reads in the whole file and then generates large in-memory lists of the parsed data before processing it.

They do this because because of the expectation that current systems have more than enough resources and processing power, and that their code won't be used to process larger sets of data. This assumption may hold for a few years, until the accumulation of inefficient modules begins to cause the software hosting such modules to bog systems down. And they can't always foresee how the size of certain types of files will grow over time.

IDE plugins that process source file text (among other things) that use inefficient algorithms for handling data for instance, contribute to IDE's consuming a very large portion of RAM and they eventually begin to make the IDE run slow and affect the performance of other open applications.

Reading in large sets of data can't always be avoided, but where it can be, it should. One shouldn't get bogged down in their work focusing on "early optimization", but I feel that if you know how to write efficient code, you should take the time to do it right the first time before you leave a project and other people inherit your code and never identify it as part of a larger problem and never fix it.

Chrome is another example of an application affected by memory overconsumption. I can't even have it open in my VM if I have an IDE open or my VM will nearly grind to a halt.